# Draggable columns reorder with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I wonder if you can create a table with columns that I reorder when I drag them. I know there is dragtable framework, but need to do this do this using only JavaScript, jQuery or jQueryUI without using other external frameworks. Could someone help me please?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
   <th>Sex</th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
   <td>Peter</td>
   <td>22</td>
   <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>24</td>
   <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Jane</td>
   <td>26</td>
   <td>Female</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Ralf</td>
   <td>24</td>
   <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Mary</td>
   <td>24</td>
   <td>Female</td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:

I just did the ordering of the rows, the ordering of the columns do not know how
https://jsfiddle.net/xgagdas4/

Comment: As you must know it is possible using jquery-ui-sortable...what have you tried so far??

Comment: @RakeshGR Hello, I just did the ordering of rows using the sortable method jQueryUI but ordanção column did not get.

Comment: @RakeshGR I've edited the post with the code. I need to do the reordering of table columns